# Qt displaying different scenes on events

Tags: c++, qt, scene

I have a board game I would like to initialize by allowing the player to change up a few options like how wide he wants the game board to be and how many players will be participating. I have the actual game basically all set up, but I need the intial scene (setting up values, two sliders probably) to show before I show the actual game scene. And I want to show the game scene only when the user clicks a GO button.

I tried abstracting from what I have to an algorithm like this:

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene();
// setting up the scene, adding items like sliders and buttons
show();
// now I want to wait for a clickButton event and....
scene2 = new QGraphicsScene(); // etc..?
```

Is this doable? Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: Do you want to create initial form using graphics scene or just a normal widget with standard sliders, etc?

Comment: @PavelStrakhov it doesn't matter as long as it has the functionality I described..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create main designer form class (let's name it `GameForm`) and add a graphics view to it. Add constructor arguments for each configurable option. In the constructor you should set up a scene considering specified arguments.

Create another designer form class (let's name it `SettingsForm`) and fill it with needed sliders and go button. In the button's clicked slot write the following code:

```
void SettingsForm::on_go_clicked() {
  int param1 = ui->slider1->value();
  int param2 = ui->slider2->value();
  hide();
  deleteLater();
  GameForm *gameForm = new GameForm(param1, param2);
  gameForm->show();
}
```

In the main function create a settings form:

```
SettingsForm* form = new SettingsForm();
form->show();
```